# TypeScript : Spread only excess properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-2016

Using typescript in react, I have a interface for my component which has some necessary properties but I want to be able to pass extra properties and grab only those excess properties.
Please check the broken code below for expected result

```js
interface InputFieldProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  type?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  [otherProps: string]: unknown;
}

const InputField = (props: InputFieldProps) => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={props.name}>
        {props.label}
      </label>
      <Field
        id={props.name}
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type ? props.type : undefined}
        placeholder={props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : undefined}
        // Spread otherProps here
        {...props.otherProps}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you rest the other properties into `otherProps`? You can do this while destructuring the props.

Try this:

```
interface InputFieldProps {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  type?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}

const InputField = ({
  name,
  label,
  type,
  placeholder,
  ...otherProps
}: InputFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <Field
        id={name}
        name={name}
        type={type ? type : undefined}
        placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : undefined}
        // Spread otherProps here
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

You can also add an alias to the destructured props to avoid conflicts.

```
const InputField = ({
  name: nameProp,
  label: labelProp,
  type,
  placeholder,
  ...otherProps
}: InputFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={nameProp}>{labelProp}</label>
      <Field
        id={nameProp}
        name={nameProp}
        type={type ? type : undefined}
        placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : undefined}
        // Spread otherProps here
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: A clever technique, it is possible but the props when destructured  give out label and name const that are scoped to InputField function and causes conflict , will it be possible without extracting label and name prop ?

Comment: We're extracting name, label etc. so that the remaining properties go into `otherProps` but not all. If they cause conflict then you can always rename the variables causing the conflict. You can also rename the destructured props, see the updated answer.